# Where to best store data on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

If my end goal is to run a machine learning model on some CSV data, where should I best store my data file?

- In a bucket,
- in BigQuery, or
- as a dataset under Vertex AI?

It seems that these three options can lead to overlap/redundancies in storage. Is there a practical reason why a basic CSV would have so many options for storage?

Comment: Each storage is optimized for a specific task. So yes, it's normal.

Comment: Is there an overview of of which storage is best for which task? This info doesn't seem to be centralized anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to train a ML model in vertex AI, the best way to store data in Vertex-AI dataset.

Vertex-AI Datasets make data discoverable from a central place and provide the ability to annotate and label the data within the UI. You can upload your CSV data into the dataset on the basis of where your data resides ie. in GCS, BigQuery or local storage.

Is there a practical reason why a basic CSV would have so many options for storage? It is based on a people's requirement. If someone wants to query and visualize the data they need not go for creating Vertex-AI datasets, they can directly upload data to BQ and get insights.